# Use Camera as a Service in newer Android API-s

Tags: android, camera

I would like to make an application which works similar to a dashcam in the car but it should take pictures instead of video let's say in every 5 seconds.

I figured it must be done in a Service, because if a call comes in during the recording, the Activity goes to background and the recording stops.

I heard there are some restrictions for the newer Android API-s to use the Camera as a Service.

How could I implement this in newer Android API-s?